# Executable Jar cannot find typesafe/config application.conf on classpath

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, typesafe-config

I have a command line app that downloads some reports, processes them, then uploads data to Google Drive. I'm using [Typesafe-Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/README.md#api-example) for all the magic strings I need. Typesafe-Config looks on the classpath for my application.conf file and uses HOCON to map config objects to fields in my class, like this:

From `~/configs/application.conf`:

`my.homePageUrl = "https://my.home.com"`

From `MyClass.java`:

```
private static Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
private static final String HOME_URL = config.getString("my.homePageUrl");
```

I'm using the `maven-shade-plugin` to build an executable .jar for easy deployment on a remote server. The plugin looks like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Main-Class>com.my.reports.ReportRunner</Main-Class>
                                <Class-Path>~/configs/application.conf</Class-Path>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The problem is, when I run the executable .jar, `application.conf` isn't found on my classpath (I guess this also could be a bug in the typesafe code). All this works just fine in Intellij.

```
dustinevan@iMac:~/bin$ java -jar my-reports-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'my'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getList(SimpleConfig.java:212)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getHomogeneousUnwrappedList(SimpleConfig.java:271)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getStringList(SimpleConfig.java:329)
    at com.stellarliving.reports.ecp.ReportRunner.<clinit>(ReportRunner.java:19)

dustinevan@iMac:~/configs$ ls
total 8
-rw-r--r--@  1 dustinevan  staff  1520 Jun 13 01:16 application.conf
```

I've tried MANY permutations, and done lots of reading to solve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I just had the same problem...

The `-jar` overrides all classpath settings, so only the jar is seen. `-Dconfig.trace=loads` will show what is seen by java.

We want the application.conf on the classpath, as well as the jar, so:
`java -cp .:my-reports-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar full.path.to.main.Main`
did the trick for me. application.conf found and overrides reference.conf in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

I also had that issue. I've noticed that you use a `Class-Path` declaration in shaded configuration, so I've merged the [answer by Lothar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997835/4464702) with your info and added:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>com.my.reports.ReportRunner</Main-Class>
            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
    </manifestEntries>
</transformer>
```